# Im getting RuntimeException ,how can i fix it?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to print an exception of division in zero but its not working :
this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int d=0; 
        Scanner S=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Please Enter an integer :");
        try{
            d=S.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println(1/d);    
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.print("%s",e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "but its not working" what does it do instead?

Comment: Why not just do `System.out.println(1/0)`?

Comment: i know its working and i dont know why , it should print an exception message when dividing by zero .

Comment: What's your input? Have you used debugger?

Comment: because i want to print that using my exception object  e and not with system.out.println

Comment: Still, you don't need a `Scanner` to get `0`.

Comment: Sally, @Izruo 's comment applies to your minimal posted program, not to answer your question.  That would make your example even simpler and still show the issue..)

Comment: Using JDK8, I get a compile error: 
The method print(String) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArithmeticException).  Use `printf` or remove the "%s" argument.

Comment: In the future, make sure your code compiles without errors, or else post the compiler error message that you don't understand.

Comment: Are you looking for `e.printStackTrace();` ? which prints the whole exception but not using System.out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work for me, unless I change the print to printf:

```
System.out.printf("%s", e);
```

But as you can see in the Documentation of java.lang.ArithmeticException

> [..] an integer "divide by zero" throws an instance of this class[..]

But the result of a division is in your case Integer, since you are dividing two integer values, but it would make more senes to receive a double or float value and in both cases that Exception is not thrown (result of the division is Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY).

Which means you have to add a check if your variable "d" equlas 0. If it is zero then handle it (e.g. print a message).

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think division by zero will be Double.NAN. I think thats even how NAN is defined.

Comment: System.out.println("" + (double) 5 / 0); delivers infinity

Comment: You're right, the case I was thinking about then was `0d/0`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it - you need a printf("%s", e) statement instead of the current print statement you have. Then, if you enter 0 when you enter a number, it should point the division by zero error.